# 504 error how to fix this select count error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 504 gateway timeout error in my php script, how can I split this script or what can I do to fix this error

```
$mp3FilesOnServer = getDirContents($uploadsDir);

$newMp3FilesOnServer = array();

foreach ($mp3FilesOnServer as $fileFullPath) {
    $fileName = preg_replace('#^.*?([\/\\\\]+wp-content.*)$#', '$1', $fileFullPath);
    $fileName = str_replace('\\', '/', $fileName);
    $query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' 
        LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->posts . ' ON ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id  
        WHERE meta_key = "mp3file_name" AND meta_value LIKE %s AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_status != "trash"', $fileName);
    $isDb = (int) $wpdb->get_var($query);

    if (!$isDb)
        $newMp3FilesOnServer[] = array(
            'fullPath' => $fileFullPath,
            'name' => $fileName
        );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but we certainly cannot tell you whether your code is slow or whatever. Remember that we cannot look over your shoulder, so you will need to tell us everything that is relevant. First, obviously, you need to check if your database tables are indexed correctly, so whether your sql query has a good performance. MySQL offers the "explain" feature for that, check the official documentation to learn how to use it.

Comment: If optimizing the database is not enough you might want to optimize the query. For example you are using a `LIKE` operator, that one is _extremely_ slow, search engines do not work that way. For a better performance you need to create a specific search table that holds all separated words, then you can use a normal "equals" operator instead of the "LIKE" operator.

Comment: And certainly you also need to take into account the total number of files you process in a single go. PHP is not really made for processing big data loads though that certainly is possible. Maybe you have to change your architecture to a more asynchonous approach.

Comment: Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when `INNER JOIN` is what you need, it's not as efficient. This query doesn't look like it should use `LEFT JOIN` at all -- it will return `1` when there aren't any matching posts.